# Berkson's Paradox: How does further conditioning increase the negative correlation?

Tags: paradox

I don't understand the bolded sentence beneath from [Cory Simon's](http://corysimon.github.io/) [BSc Ohio, PhD UBC](https://www.pims.math.ca/scientific/graduate-training-igtc/mathematical-biology/students/cory-simon) [old blog](http://mathemathinking.blogspot.com/2014/10/berksons-paradox.html).  How's negative correlation in the red triangle  $<$ (to wit, 'more severe') negative correlation in green triangle?

> From this natural compromising behavior in her dating criterion, many of the best-looking guys that this girl dates are not so nice; many of the nicest guys she dates are not as good-looking. By restricting herself to this set of guys, she sees a negative correlation between looks and niceness, *despite* these two variables being independent in the population! This is Berkson's paradox, and now you can see that this induced correlation stems from selection bias.
>
> We can go one step further: maybe the guys in the very top-right corner (red points) are so nice and handsome that they will not consider dating the girl we are considering, who is just decently nice and good-looking.

[image]

> Now her dating pool is even more restricted due to selection bias, and **the negative correlation between good looks and niceness is even more severe**.

Comment: It's not that the negative correlation in the red triangle < the negative correlation in the green band, it's that the negative correlation in the green band > the negative correlation in (the green band + the red triangle.)   The girl can't access the red-triangle guys (in the one-step-further scenario) because they won't date her.

Comment: @jbowman Thanks. Would you like to answer so that I can upvote you?

Comment: Sure!  Let me expand upon the comment a little in the answer.  Thanks!